# Why isn't my bash script working?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get this bash script to work but am at a loss. I have a text file that contains a list of frame numbers line by line. ffmpeg reports the error:

```
Undefined constant or missing '(' in '$name)'
```

The script

```
#!/bin/bash
source text.txt
while read name
do
 ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,\$name)'" -vframes 1 frame-$i.jpg
done <text.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, the \ goes before the ,

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,$name)'" -vframes 1 frame-$i.jpg`?

Comment: 'eq(n,\$name)' -> 'eq(n,\${name})' and try again ?

Comment: @heemayl that worked thanks.

Comment: I get this error <File 'frame-.jpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Not overwriting - exiting>. I think the $i variable is not changing when naming the clip for some reason. What have I got wrong? Thanks.

Comment: In fact this is the error I get first for each frame:< bash: 178: command not found>. Any ideas what I've got wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping the `$` before variable name i.e. `$name`, so the `$name` will be treated literally without any variable expansion being done.

Do:

```
ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,$name)'" -vframes 1 frame-$i.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. I run the script and it stops as soon as it comes to creating the second thumbnail with <File 'frames-.jpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Not overwriting - exiting>.  I did try <ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,$name)'" -vframes 1 frame%03d.jpg> but not luck.

Comment: @JulianJ That's a different question I think.. Could you please ask it as a new question making this one accepted..